zeros by using partial fraction expansion and complex analysis
I want to know zeros of a complex function.  The definition of Laplace transform is
$$\mathcal{L}\{\Gamma(\nu,at\}(p)~=~\Gamma(\nu)p^{-1}\left(1-\left(1+\frac{p}{a}\right)^{-\nu}\right)~~~~~~\text{Re}~\nu>-1,\,\text{Re}~p>-\text{Re}~a$$
My question:
$$f(z)=\begin{cases}{1\over z}&\text{if }z\not=0\\0&\text{if }z=0\end{cases}$$
Analyticity of $g$  at $z=a$  necessitates analyticity of $f$ at $z=a$. In contrast, while displaying the functional value of a real function $ f(x)$ at a point $x=a$  of its domain.
The laplace transform of complex zeros is :
$$L_{k+1}(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{t^ke^{-t/\theta}}{k!\theta^{k+1}}e^{-ts}\mathrm dt=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{t^ke^{-t\left(s+\frac 1\theta\right)}}{k!\theta^{k+1}}\mathrm dt$$
My effort
The function $f$ is analytic on one side of this arc. Extending $f$
with the value $0$  to the points of $C$ makes it continuous on $D∪C$  and real valued on $C$. It follows that $f$ can be extended analytically to the outside of $C$ by putting
$$\tilde f(z):=\overline{f(1/\bar z)}\qquad\bigl(|z|>1\bigr)\ ,$$

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Well, if $\alpha$ is a complex number, there are precisely $k$ numbers $z_n$ s.t. $z_n^k=\alpha$, namely $z_n=|\alpha|^{\frac{1}{k}}e^{2\pi in/k}$ for $n=0,1,..,k-1$. It follows that if $\omega^k=\delta^k=\alpha$, then $\omega=\delta e^{2\pi ir/k}$. For some $r=0,1,...,k-1$
Now, assuming $s\neq 0$, the denumerator is $0$ when $(b+s)^k=2b^k$, so we must have $b+s=2^{1/k}be^{2\pi ir/k}$ which can be rewritten as $s=b(2^{1/k}e^{2\pi ir/k}-1)$
Update: the idea the author has in mind is to consider 2 polynomials $q(s)=\frac {(b+s)^k-b^k }{s}$ and $p(s)=(b+s)^k-2b^k$. The later has $k$ different roots $a_r=b(2^{1/k}e^{2\pi ir/k}-1)$ for $r=0,1,...,k-1$. To see this, put $p(s)=0$ and rewrite it as $(b+s)^k=2b^k$. From the discussion above (with $\omega=b+s$ and $\delta=2^{1/k}b$) we conclude that $p(s)=0$ whenever $s=b(2^{1/k}e^{2\pi ir/k}-1)$, $r=0,1,...,k-1$. Put $a_r=b(2^{1/k}e^{2\pi ir/k}-1)$ for each such $r$. Since $degree[q(s)]=k-1$ and $degree[p(s)]=k$, we can use partial fraction decomposition to get $\frac{q(s)}{p(s)}=\sum_{r=0}^{k-1} \frac {A_r}{s-a_r}$ where $A_r=\lim_{s \to a_r}\frac{(s-a_r)q(s)}{p(s)}$. The rest follows from theory of Laplace transforms and the fact that $\int\limits_0^{\infty}e^{-st}A_re^{a_rt}dt=\frac{A_r}{s-a_r}$ for $s$ with sufficiently large real part.

No, no. $a_r=b(2^{1/k}e^{2\pi ir/k}-1)$, these are roots of the polynomial $p(s)=(b+s)^k-2b^k$. To solve for them, you set $p(s)=0$ and rewrite it as $(b+s)^k=2b^k$ then take $k$th root of both sides and rearrange terms to get $s=b(2^{1/k}e^{2\pi ir/k}-1)$, so there are $k$ different solutions corresponding to $r=0,...,k-1$, denote each solution as $a_r$.

I added some further clarifications, maybe they'll be more helpful

$A_r$ are constants. You can find them using the formula $\lim_{s \to a_r}\frac{(s-a_r)q(s)}{p(s)}$. So, in your example, $A_1=\lim_{s \to a_1}\frac{(s-a_1)q(s)}{p(s)}=\frac{q_0+q_1 a_1+ q_2 a_1^2}{(a_1-a_2) (a_1-a_3)}$ etc.
